# How to programmatically get the pid of a socket's peer in MacOS?

Tags: macos

In MacOS, other than launching `lsof` command, is there way to get the process id of a socket's peer from within a TCP server that is bound to localhost? If there isn't, is `lsof` guaranteed to be present in all OSX versions starting from 10.11 (El Capitan)?

EDIT: The server process is running within the current user context (it does not have elevated privileges). And the connecting process is also expected to be running at the same privilege level.

TIA.

Comment: The problem is that unless you have a guaranteed local socket (i.e. an `AF_LOCAL` socket) then you don't know where the peer is running. It could be locally, or across the world.

Comment: Also, what is the underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need to get the pid of the peer?

Comment: Like I updated, only local processes are expected to connect to the server. The goal is to verify the authenticity of the connecting process. That is only certain specific processes are allowed to use the TCP server.

Answer (score 3):

There is, but it's very proprietary and won't work outside Darwin. You can use the  com.apple.network.statistics PF_SYSTEM socket to effectively do what netstat(1) and the Darwin-specific nettop(1) do, and get all socket activity (including updated in real time).

The private NetworkStatistics.framework even contains wrappers for this and (so far) it doesn't need entitlements or root privileges. Check the code sample in Listing 16-26 at http://newosxbook.com/bonus/vol1ch16.html for exact details, and couple that with getpeername(2).

FYI, this *still* isn't a good idea, because any process can easily spoof its name. If you're already in macOS and you are dealing with code signed processes, a much better option is, once you have the PID in hand, to use the csops(2) system call to obtain the code signing identity, which can't be spoofed.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, once the PID is obtained, system call has to be used to verify the process binary. I found this API - SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath - that might just do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly easy, despite the apparent ignorance around the Internet of this solution.  LOCAL_PEERPID is your friend here.

```
#include <socket/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...

pid_t pid = -1;
len = sizeof(pid);
if (getsockopt(socket_id, SOL_LOCAL, LOCAL_PEERPID, &pid, &len) == -1) {
    printf("failed: %d\n", errno);
} else {
    printf("pid: %d\n", pid);
}
```

Comment: That's good to know. Tks. This was for a friend who eventually managed to work around this using another approach. I remember it being way harder than your solution. A bit late of a reply, but it's good to know. Tks again.